# Accidentally deleted local git files (uncommitted). Is there any way to get them back?

Tags: git, github

I am very new to git. I had made a lot of changes to a branch locally and wanted to upload it. But I accidentally clicked "Fetch origin" in github desktop and that overwrote my local files. I lost most of my code. Then I tried to fix it by going into git bash and writing some commands (see picture) but I think I made it worse.

Is there any way to restore my local files?

[image: Image of commands entered in gitbash.]

Comment: `git reset --hard` blows away both changes on disk and staged changes. If the changes were not committed Git cannot recover them. Sorry. You'd have to use something outside of Git, a backup or file recovery tool.

Comment: The "Fetch Origin" button does not change your local files. It pulls down a fresh snapshot of the remote repository, but does not merge it. It is safe to push that button when you feel like it. Something else happened.

Comment: I have two separate pieces of advice for you. Unfortunately I don't think they will help you in your current situation but others might be able to shed more light. For instance, if you added the file to the index it may be that there is a copy in the git object database. Anyway, here's my advice: 1) Read a tutorial, get some proper tutoring on the use of git and how it works. Git is the defacto standard in distributed source control and this can only help you in your career.

Comment: 2) If you end up in a bad situation, step away from the keyboard. If you don't know how you got there, don't do more random stuff that you don't fully understand. Almost none of the problems and situations you can get into will get worse by themselves, so seek help before you mess it up further.

Comment: By default git does not keep any copy of any file that you don't tell it about. If you *added* the files, you just never got around to committing them, then git already made a copy of it but it's going to take a bit of work getting them back. Do you know if you added the files you lost to the git index at all?

Comment: Do not post pictures of code. Post _code_. Your terminal entries are text, just copy and paste and format.

Comment: I can't make out the picture very well (that's one reason why text is so much better) but your `reflog` does not support your story. It looks to me like _you_ said `git reset` in some way, and _that_ is what threw away all your edits. It is very mysterious why you keep saying `reset` like that; I would suggest you learn Git before using it, as `reset` is potentially very dangerous and is a relatively rare thing to say.

Answer (score 0):

All changes that you actually created commits for are still recoverable. Anything else, I think is gone due to the `git reset --hard [sha]` command you issued on the terminal.

Ok; in my opinion, you should not get starting using git without using some sort of Git GUI. There are many out there, and most should work fine, but I'm going to specifically instruct using [GitExtensions](https://gitextensions.github.io/) because I see you are on windows and I know it is quite user-friendly. It has one particular feature which I haven't seen in any other GUIs; `View > Show reflog`. This shows you all commits that have been made, not just those that reachable from branches, in the tree-view.

1. Install GitExtensions
2. Open your repository using that
3. Select `View > Show reflog references`

Next, look around carefully; is there an indication you are currently in the middle of a merge or a rebase? Are there unstaged changes? The number next to 'Commit' shows the number of unstaged changes; commit those if they are there. As long as a change makes it into some commit, it can't really be lost anymore by other git operations. And if you have the reflog references visible, you also can't lose things by making them unreachable, so you should just be able to play around and make branches and fetch without worrying too much.

You probably need to identify the commit in the reflog that contains the files you need, create a branch with a new name there, and push that to the remote. But let me know by comments if you have more questions.